# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. dealing with input()

Tags: python

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?

```
import json
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from difflib import get_close_matches

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def translate(word):
    match = get_close_matches(word,data.keys(),cutoff=0.8)
    if word.lower() in data:
        return data[word.lower()]
    elif len(match) > 1:
        yn = input("Did you mean %s? Enter y or n" %match[0])
    else:
        return "Not in the dictionary. Please check again."

input = input("What is your word? ")

print(translate(input))`

What is your word? caca
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dictionary.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(translate(input))
  File "dictionary.py", line 12, in translate
    yn = input("Did you mean %s? Enter y or n" %match[0])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: you assigned a string to `input` it seems. `input = input("What is your word? ")` is the problem. rename the variable, `input` is reserved

Comment: ...`input` is a _variable_ in Python. Normally it holds a reference to a function that prompts the CLI user for a line of text. When you wrote `input("...")`, that tries to call the value of `input`, which normally is a function, and all is good. But then you wrote `input = ...`, and that assigned a new value, a string, to `input`. So the next time it got to `input("...")` it tried to call the string. But that didn't work because `'str' object is not callable.`

Comment: You should use a content manager to handle file objects. I recommend using f-strings for string formatting. Also note that the `yn` variable is useless, since it is thrown away immediately.